# Windows Phone 7 - Map PushPin not moving with the map?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pushpin

Bit of a weird one. I've recently started WP7 development and trying to port over an iOS app I have written. One part of the application involves placing a pin on a map using a latitude and longitude. I have this working fine using:

```
  Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
  Location location = new Location();
  location.Latitude = lat;
  location.Longitude = lng;
  pushpin.Location = location;
  pushpin.Name = name;
  MyMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
```

The pin appears fine, however when I drag the map or Zoom, the pin stays at the centre point of the screen and not in its location relevant to the map. So if the user drags the map left, the pin stays in it's position at the centre of the screen rather than sticking to it's coordinate on the map.

Is there something I need to be setting but I am currently missing? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you might benefit from making use of the GeoCoordinate class and a ViewModel to bind your location data to application controls.

A few samples have just been published that should be able to help you. The Geo-Location iPhone to Windows Phone migration sample (http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/iphone-to-windows-phone-geo-location) is directly applicable to your situation. You can download both the iOS and Windows Phone samples via links at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Your specified location is invalid. If it's not a valid `GeoCoordinate`, it'll stay fixed in the middle of the screen.

I'm not sure why you're using a `Location` since that's the Silverlight class, not the Windows Phone class, for the Pushpin. Are you certain you're adding the right references and using the right pushpin type?

Your code shouldn't even compile, if you used the right assembly for Bing Maps, which are the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps` assembly.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447 for a good tutorial about how to use pushpins.

Comment: Just look over the tutorial I followed and seem it was for Silverlight. I'll try this and report back. Seems to be where I'm going wrong though. Thanks very much for your help.