# pushpin.Location error on Bing maps for Windows store app

Tags: windows-8, location, bing-maps, windows-store-apps, pushpin

I'm using C# to create a windows store app using bing maps. I am trying to store and retrieve the location of a randomly placed pushpin on a map but when I use pushpin.Location for trying to print the location for example, I get the following error:

> 'Bing.Maps.Pushpin' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and
>   no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Bing.Maps.Pushpin' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

The simple code example below show what I mean a bit more clearly:

```
private async void pushpinTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
      MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("You are here" + pushPin.Location());
      await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

It states clearly that location is a property of the the pushpin class in the API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.pushpin_properties.aspx)
There's also examples of it being used for windows phone 7, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679979/windows-phone-7-map-pushpin-not-moving-with-the-map).

Any ideas what I'm missing? or is this functionality not available for Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like:

```
async void pin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Pushpin pin = sender as Pushpin;
            Location pinLocation = MapLayer.GetPosition(pin);
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("You are here: " + pinLocation.Latitude +", " + pinLocation.Longitude);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah nice one thank you. 
I found another way to do it too. Essentially the same thing but using `var x` instead of Location.

```
private async void pushpinTapped(object sender,Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Pushpin tappedpin = sender as Pushpin;  
     if (null == tappedpin) return;  
     var x = MapLayer.GetPosition(tappedpin); 
     MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("You are here " + x.Latitude + ", " + x.Longitude);
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Cool. At runtime, var will be resolved to Location. It's the same, No harm.